# How to send an email message to seller when user press on a specific button(Wordpress Auction Theme)

Tags: php, wordpress, email

So, I am using Wordpress Auction Theme. I want the seller to receive an email when someone bid on their product. The theme itself has an email setup where you can set this kind of messages. But there is not an option for such thing I want.

So I had an idea when someone press on the bid button, that it automaticaly send already written message to seller.

Is that even possible? I have tryed many php scripts such as:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Send details to embassy" />
    <input type="hidden" name="button_pressed" value="1" />
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['button_pressed']))
{
    $to      = 'nobody@example.com';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'hello';
    $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    echo 'Email Sent.';
}

?>
```

I don't want to change the button to be like this : input type. It's a simple div with styling. Is that possible?
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Use wp_mail function instead of mail()  to send email same like..

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['button_pressed']))
{
    $to      = 'abc@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'the subject';
    $message = 'hello';
    $headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
        'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    wp_mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

    echo 'Email Sent.';
}
?>
```

[Click here to show more detail for wp_mail](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_mail/)

Comment: Where should I put the code? And how to indicate the specific div , and how to indicate the enail to send to sellers email? Thanks for helping by the way,it means me a lot!

Comment: This is not working still,I put the code in my child theme's functions.php

Comment: Don't put in functions.php put this code before your form.

Comment: I can't I don't have html file. It's all in php files